# There is a way to auto upgrade skills using a pre-made build?

Tags: dota-2

I created a pre-made build and the UI shows me what to upgrade next, can this be automatically done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No** unlike the *"auto-purchase items"* option there is no such option for skills.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this. Honestly, I don't think you would want to either. There are many times when you will want to skill a hero differently based on the other team's lineup and being stuck in one build could cripple you. Imagine playing the same items in the same order every time you played a hero.